# Duplicate got reopened by a gold-badge user who answered it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

A couple of weeks ago I asked in SOCVR chat room to help close the question [How to calculate moving average using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14313510/7851470) as a duplicate of [Moving average or running mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13728392/7851470).

Today, I see that it got single-handedly reopened by a gold-badge user who already had an answer under the first one.

I strongly believe that the closure was justified. The first question was posted later, has fewer answers, and less traffic. So, I don't know why they reopened it.

Could people who know [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and specifically [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy), take a look at the aforementioned questions and consider closing the first one?

Answer (score 8):

While [Moving average or running mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean) does have more traffic (the second duplicate [Finding moving average from data points in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352047/finding-moving-average-from-data-points-in-python)
 does not), in my opinion the question set as a duplicate basically contains all logical and **performant** approaches  to compute a moving average and mostly explained in depth. And I'm stressing performant here since the title of the question does mention *using NumPy*. While the question set as a dupe has a clear contradiction, OP appears to be explicitly asking for a solution using `SciPy` or `NumPy` but the accepted answer uses lists and for loops. That shouldn't really mean anything, but it can be misleading to future viewers, since the accepted answer will perform quite poorly on large sequences.

So even though someone looking for an answer to this problem finds [How to calculate moving average using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy/54628145#54628145) rather than the dupe, I can't see why there's a need to reference the mentioned duplicates, as the question contains in my opinion all useful and performant answers to this problem both in NumPy and in Pandas.

[Moving average or running mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean) does indeed contain very complete answers, and it's not that I have an interest the question not being closed, but for the mentioned reasons I can't see why it is necessary to set it as a duplicate, and that is basically why I decided to reopen it. That being said, I would not mind at all closing it again if a majority of users disagree with this.