# How can we prevent "close/opening wars" between gold tag badge holders around possible duplicates with only-code-no-explanation answers?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, tag-badges

I have seen many cases of questions closed as duplicate by a gold tag badge holder that later are reopened by other tag badge holders that have answered those questions with *code-only-no-explanation-at-all* answers. There are at least two.

Typically these *code-only-no-explanation-at-all* answers are only helpful to the OP, i.e. they fix a "newbie" error, or provide a spreadsheet formula, among other "too localized solutions".

I'm convinced that questions that are answered by a previous post should be closed as a duplicate ASAP, with few exceptions like:

1. It's easier to post an answer than finding the duplicate, but still open to close it as duplicate later.
2. The answers doesn't look good for "anyone who write code" and it will take a time to improve the answers and/or to post a "better" answer.
3. There is an active discussion<sup>1</sup>  to clarify the question that might lead to have an original question, i.e., some already pointed to the OP to a previous question, the commenters are asking for more details and the OP is quickly answering them.

I have read suggestions that might work on isolate cases, i.e. discuss the case in the tag / subject matter chatroom and create a discussion here. I'm open to try these suggestions but I'm afraid that will not go well based on my previous interactions with these specific gold tag badge holders.

Besides the above suggestions,

*Is there is something that should be done before my next close as duplicate of one of the questions having a *only-code-no-explanation* answer from these / any gold tag badge holders?*

Notes:

1. Multiple comments in a very short time. It might be better to "get a room" but the OP might be new / low rep user without the privilege to use the chat.

---

I just found this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372685/1595451) from 2018 to [Am I justified to answer a question which I have closed as a duplicate earlier but was reopened later by another gold badge holder?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372613/1595451) for a very similar situation (emphasis mine to highlight the one of the differences)

> If the user reopened just **to answer the question**, and it's still a blatant dupe, then it's clearly abuse (I already stumbled on that once at least: [Is it possible to know who single-handedly reopened a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361469/is-it-possible-to-know-who-single-handedly-reopened-a-question), also handy if you don't know who reopened the question), so comment / downvote accordingly or get help from meta or chatrooms to get it closed again.

In this case before the questions were closed, the gold tag badge holders have posted the *code-only-no-explanation-at-all* answers.

Another difference is that I have observed this behavior in the past and have other disagreements with these gold tag badge holders.

Related

- [What can be done if a question that was closed by the review process is re-opened by a Gold Badge holder incorrectly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382402/1595451)
- [Duplicate got reopened by a gold-badge user who answered it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394425/1595451)

Comment: Flag it for a moderator to handle

Comment: @SecurityHound  I'm interested in How exactly would that help.  Code-only answers are deemed  acceptable by meta and the community. Moderators  may not be SMEs. What do you expect a moderator to do?

Comment: "It's easier to post an answer than finding the duplicate, but still open to close it as duplicate later." I'm not sure what that is supposed to say. I'm *guessing* it means that duplicate closure may be skipped in favour of answering if only the question is simple enough. But isn't that exactly the kind of question that attracts code-only answers?

Comment: @TheMaster if a user is abusing the dupehammer, that's a matter for moderators to deal with. We simple users have no tools for that. They may not be subject matter experts for every tag out there, but it's not hard for a moderator to come in and look at the overall situation/pattern of such users to see if it's something they're abusing. If they find there's no there there, then there's no there there.

Comment: Using their brains and critical thinking skills. If they need to they can even reach out to subject matter experts for an opinion.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Please post that as an answer. It will be easier to discuss that there.

Comment: @Rubén It's very clearly not an answer to this meta-question, so I don't see why I should post it as such.

Answer (score -2):

So far<sup>rev 4</sup> [Security Hound's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421005/how-to-prevent-close-opening-wars-between-gold-tag-badge-holders-around-possib#comment931025_421005) has 9 upvotes:

> Flag it for a moderator to handle

IMHO it looks like that's the best way to proceed because the reopener doesn't look to be open

- to discuss the merits of the *close-as-duplicate-target* (does it really answers the closed question?)
- to improve the closed question to clarify why the question shouldn't be closed as duplicate
- improve the their answer to the reopened question a best target for closing questions as duplicates

Moderators might not be SME but it's not their role to judge the posts, their role is to assure that users follow the rules formal ( the help articles, code of conduct) and informal ( community common practices) included the appropriate use of the user privileges.

Comment: While I agree with this specifically, comment votes cannot be considered as consensus as a important factor in deciding the consensus, downvotes are missing.

Comment: Flag on what grounds? Moderators are usually not judging based on subject expertise and that is exactly what the (anti-) mjolnir is there for. Reopening and answering may well indicate an incorrect *closure* instead of just an incorrect reopening.

Comment: @TheMaster answer edited.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi answer edited (the question is about the case that the reopener only reopens the questions without improving the question, answer, leaving a comment on the question, chat or posting a question on Meta.

Comment: @Rubén I don't see how any of that violates formal or informal rules. Perhaps opening a meta-discussion yourself might be a good idea in this case; involving a moderator via flagging seems like overkill.